# How to mock a file attachment size in Apex Salesforce to test

Tags: apex, class, mock

I have to test a method that return a boolean false when the attachment upload is bigger than 25 megas, I tried to test this one using the code below but there is a limit dml exception string too long, besides I tried to cut them in pieces more smaller but the problem is with cpu apex clock, any idea to resolve this? Any help would be appreciated

```
    public static Boolean  verifySizeAttachment(String caseId){
    Boolean validation = true;
    AggregateResult[] lstAttachment = [SELECT  SUM(ContentDocument.ContentSize)
                                        FROM ContentDocumentLink
                                        WHERE LinkedEntityId =: caseId and 
                                        ContentDocument.Description = 'Send Email'];
        
    if(lstAttachment.size() > 0){           
        Double size = (Double) lstAttachment[0].get('expr0');          
        if(size > 25000000){                
            validation = false;                
            list<ContentDocumentLink> lstAttachmentDelete = [SELECT Id
                                                            FROM ContentDocumentLink
                                                            WHERE LinkedEntityId =: caseId and 
                                                            ContentDocument.Description = 'Send Email' limit 1];              
            delete lstAttachmentDelete;    
            }         
        }
        
        return validation; 
    }
    }

//TEST CLASSES

    //STEP 1
    ContentVersion version = new ContentVersion();
    version.Title= 'File Name';
    version.PathOnClient = 'sample.pdf';
    version.VersionData=blob.valueOf('Test Content data');
    version.Description= 'Send Email';
    insert version;
    
    version = [SELECT ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.ContentSize FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = : version.Id];
    
    //STEP 2
    ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
    cdl.ContentDocumentId = version.ContentDocumentId;
    cdl.LinkedEntityId = newCase.Id;
    insert cdl;
    
    
    Test.startTest();
    // VERIFY LESS THAN 25mb - TRUE
    Boolean validation =  AttachmentController.verifySizeAttachment(newCase.Id);
    System.assertEquals(true, validation);
    
    // VERIFY MORE THEN 25 MB - FALSE
   
    version.VersionData = Blob.valueOf(String.valueOf('a').repeat(26000000));
    update version;
    validation = AttachmentController.verifySizeAttachment(newCase.Id);   
    System.assertEquals(false, validation);

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: Even if you managed to not get a CPU timeout, you'd be limited by the 6/12MB heap limit, which is a hard limit for the length of any one string value. Your only real choice here would be dependency injection by faking a record. Without seeing more of your code, we can't really help you. If you'd please [edit] in the relevant parts of the AttachmentController, that'd be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have attached the sample of code above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code under test to:

```
public AttachmentController {
  @TestVisible Integer MAX_FILESIZE = 25000000;
  ...
  public static Boolean  verifySizeAttachment(String caseId){
  
    Boolean validation = true;
    AggregateResult[] lstAttachment = [SELECT  SUM(ContentDocument.ContentSize)
                                    FROM ContentDocumentLink
                                    WHERE LinkedEntityId =: caseId and 
                                    ContentDocument.Description = 'Send Email'];
    
    if(lstAttachment.size() > 0){           
    Double size = (Double) lstAttachment[0].get('expr0');          
    if(size > MAX_FILESIZE){                
        validation = false;                
    ... 
  }
}
```

Then dependency inject a smaller value to `MAX_FILESIZE` in the testmethod

```
//STEP 1 - create attachment bigger than max
AttachmentController.MAX_FILESIZE = 10;
ContentVersion version = new ContentVersion();
version.Title= 'File Name';
version.PathOnClient = 'sample.pdf';
version.VersionData=blob.valueOf('a'.repeat(MAX_FILESIZE); 
version.Description= 'Send Email';
insert version;

...
Boolean validation =  AttachmentController.verifySizeAttachment(newCase.Id);
System.assertEquals(true, validation,'attachment should be ok size');

//STEP 2 - create attachment bigger than max
Cversion = new ContentVersion();
version.Title= 'File Name';
version.PathOnClient = 'sample.pdf';
version.VersionData=blob.valueOf('a'.repeat(MAX_FILESIZE+1); 
version.Description= 'Send Email';
insert version;
...
Boolean validation =  AttachmentController.verifySizeAttachment(newCase.Id);
System.assertEquals(false, validation,'attachment too big');
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunatelly, I've received the same exeption: System.LimitException: String is too long.

Comment: I'd have to see how you modified your code under test as well as the testmethod; the above answer only creates strings of size 10 and 11

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have attached the code

Comment: Gabriel - I'm not seeing any update in the OP

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I don't know how this system works and I deleted it by mistake when I was writing the message , thank a lot for your he